How to make this program "Sargam" work under Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS?
I'm looking for help making the small program called "Sargam" work under Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
It is designed for windows, it is a small program designed to write Indian music special notations and read the special file type .srg
Here is the download link : https://sargamdev.wordpress.com/download/
Any help ?
I'm familiar with ubuntu but with low skills in programming so I have no idea where to start !
Thanks for any help

Have you tried Wine? Alternately ask the developer to port it to Linux.

Please download the .exe file from the website for best results.
